# Graphql mutation to upload file with other fields

Tags: python, graphql, ariadne-graphql

I'm using Ariadne to create a python GraphQL server and a I have the following mutation to upload a file:

```
type Mutation {
    uploadUserAvatar(file: Upload!): Boolean!
}
```

And the following curl command to upload a image:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/ \
  -F operations='{ "query":"mutation ($file: Upload!) { uploadUserAvatar(file: $file) }","variables": { "file": null} }' \
  -F map='{ "0": ["variables.file"] }' \
  -F 0=@image.jpeg
```

The command above works perfectly to upload the image into the endpoint.

But, I need to pass together with the image the user id, in a mutation like this:

```
type Mutation {
    uploadUserAvatar(userid: String!, file: Upload!): Boolean!
}
```

I'm struggling to get the correct curl command to upload the image with the `userid`.

I tried the command below

```
curl http://localhost:8080/ \
  -F operations='{ "query":"mutation ($userid: String!, $file: Upload!) { uploadUserAvatar(userid: $userid, file: $file) }","variables": { "file": null, "userid": null } }' \
  -F map='{ "0": ["variables.file"], "1": ["variables.userid"] }' \
  -F 0=@etiqueta_LG.jpeg \
  -F 1='abc1234'
```

But I'm getting this response `File data was missing for entry key '1' (https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec).`

How can I call my GraphQL endpoint passing the `userid` and the `image` for upload ?

Comment: Have you tried without the singlequotes around `abc1234`? So the last bit would be `-F 1=abc1234`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only files needs 'special treatment', other data pass in classic way, by `"variables"`.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/ \
  -F operations='{ "query":"mutation ($userid: String!, $file: Upload!) { uploadUserAvatar(userid: $userid, file: $file) }", "variables": { "file": null, "userid": "abc1234" } }' \
  -F map='{ "0": ["variables.file"] }' \
  -F 0=@image.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't wrap the `content` part of the form data like `-F name=content`, like you are doing with the userid. Try this:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/ \
  -F operations='{ "query":"mutation ($userid: String!, $file: Upload!) { uploadUserAvatar(userid: $userid, file: $file) }","variables": { "file": null, "userid": null } }' \
  -F map='{ "0": ["variables.file"], "1": ["variables.userid"] }' \
  -F 0=@etiqueta_LG.jpeg \
  -F 1=abc1234
```

I have not tried this but I read the curl docs (`man curl`) and read the section on form data `-F`.

Comment: Didn't work, getting this `File data was missing for entry key '1' (https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec)`

Comment: OK I have no other ideas. Good luck.