# Postman - Upload file and other argument with GraphQL

Tags: graphql, postman

I am trying to use Postman to upload a file to GraphQL.

I know how I can upload a file, however, in my mutation I have to pass a `String!` together with the `Upload!`.

I am not sure where I can pass this `String!` in Postman.

**My mutation:**

```
mutation AddBookImageOne($bookId: string, $bookImageOne: Upload!){
  addBookImageOne(bookId: $bookId, bookImageOne: $bookImageOne)
}
```

I tried to pass `bookId` in the `variables` key but I keep getting the error:

> "message": "Variable "$bookId" of required type "String!" was not provided.",

I checked this: [Graphql mutation to upload file with other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62682322/graphql-mutation-to-upload-file-with-other-fields)
but they use CURL

**"Operations"** in postman field is:

```
{"query":"mutation AddBookImageOne($bookId: String!, $bookImageOne: Upload!){\n  addBookImageOne(bookId: $bookId, bookImageOne: $bookImageOne)\n}"}
```

[image]

Comment: pass variables in the `operations` arg - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62683397/6124657

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**SOLVED** thanks to @xadm

I had to pass the variables in the `operations` field like:

```
{"query":"mutation AddBookImageOne($bookId: String!, $bookImageOne: Upload!){\n  addBookImageOne(bookId: $bookId, bookImageOne: $bookImageOne)\n}", "variables": { "bookImageOne": null, "bookId": "be96934c-d20c-4fad-b4bb-a1165468bad9" } }`
```

[image]

Comment: {
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "No query document supplied"
        }
    ]
}

I get the following error on trying it out this way.