# passing multiple arguments along with `GraphQLUpload` in type-graphql mutations

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, graphql-js, express-graphql, typegraphql

I'm implementing a mutation for uploading photo with type-graphql, and I also want to get another argument like and ID:

```js
  @Mutation(() => GraphQLJSON)
  async userUploadPostPhoto(
    @Arg("photo", () => GraphQLUpload) photo: Upload,
    @Arg("id") id: string,
    @Ctx() context: TContext
  ) {
    return userUploadPostPhoto(photo, context);
  }
```

This is the methods that I'm trying to test the API in postman:

[image: Screenshot from 2021-09-15 13-10-50]

The response I'm getting from the API is this json file:

```json
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Variable \"$id\" got invalid value { resolve: [function], reject: [function], promise: {} }; String cannot represent a non string value: { resolve: [function], reject: [function], promise: {} }",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 47
                }
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "BAD_USER_INPUT",
                "exception": {
                    "stacktrace": [
                        "GraphQLError: Variable \"$id\" got invalid value { resolve: [function], reject: [function], promise: {} }; String cannot represent a non string value: { resolve: [function], reject: [function], promise: {} }",
                        "    at /home/ebaqeri/Projects/univarsity/server/node_modules/graphql/execution/values.js:116:15",
                        "    at coerceInputValueImpl (/home/ebaqeri/Projects/univarsity/server/node_modules/graphql/utilities/coerceInputValue.js:131:9)",
                        "    at coerceInputValueImpl (/home/ebaqeri/Projects/univarsity/server/node_modules/graphql/utilities/coerceInputValue.js:54:14)",
                        "    at coerceInputValue (/home/ebaqeri/Projects/univarsity/server/node_modules/graphql/utilities/coerceInputValue.js:37:10)",
                        "    at _loop (/home/ebaqeri/Projects/univarsity/server/node_modules/graphql/execution/values.js:109:69)",
                        "    at coerceVariableValues (/home/ebaqeri/Projects/univarsity/server/node_modules/graphql/execution/values.js:121:16)",
                        "    at getVariableValues (/home/ebaqeri/Projects/univarsity/server/node_modules/graphql/execution/values.js:50:19)",
                        "    at buildExecutionContext (/home/ebaqeri/Projects/univarsity/server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:203:61)",
                        "    at executeImpl (/home/ebaqeri/Projects/univarsity/server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:101:20)",
                        "    at Object.execute (/home/ebaqeri/Projects/univarsity/server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:60:35)",
                        "    at execute (/home/ebaqeri/Projects/univarsity/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts:480:20)",
                        "    at Object.processGraphQLRequest (/home/ebaqeri/Projects/univarsity/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts:375:28)",
                        "    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)",
                        "    at async processHTTPRequest (/home/ebaqeri/Projects/univarsity/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/runHttpQuery.ts:331:24)"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
`
Anyone has any Idea on this? Is this the problem from the API side or the problem is the method that I'm trying to fix it?
```

Comment: IMHO `map` is/should be used for files only ... `id` should be passed via `variables`, 2nd object encoded into operations

Comment: can you please give me an example of that?

Comment: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec - you should have a variable object encoded already [with file arg nulled] - `operations` should be an array of `query` and `variables` ... as usual in mutations [or queries with args]

Comment: ```typescript
  @Mutation(() => GraphQLUpload)
  async userUploadPostPhoto(
    @Arg("photo", () => GraphQLUpload) photo: Upload,
    @Arg("id") id: string,
    @Ctx() context: TContext
  ) {
    return userUploadPostPhoto(photo, id, context);
  }
```
this is the mutation that I have implemented and this is the map object that I pass to the mutation in form-data method 
```json
{"0": ["variables.photo"], "1": ["variables.id"]}
```
I think I'm doing the same thing that was mentioned in the link that you have attched

Comment: rethink it ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63607130/6124657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will need to use the `variables` object to pass the other input, as @xadm mentioned. Using Postman, I tested the following code and it worked:

```
{
  "query": "mutation userUploadPostPhoto($photo: Upload!, $id: String!) { userUploadPostPhoto(photo: $photo, id: $id) }",
  "variables": { "photo": null, "id": "10" }
}
```

You can also remove the `photo` property, since it's not needed.

**PS**: Please ensure that you have installed `graphql-upload` and `apollo-server-express`. Another package(`apollo-server`) will not accept express as a middleware as an input to a `applyMiddleware` method.

Answer (score 3):

you can try to use [Altair](https://altair.sirmuel.design/)

I think this is better than postman here you can see an example of how to [Upload a file whit altair](https://altair.sirmuel.design/docs/features/file-upload.html)

your GraphQL query should looks like this

```
mutation ($Picture: Upload!)
{
  
  userUploadPostPhoto
  (
    id: 123123123,  
    photo: $Picture,
  )
}
```